# Simple If statement VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement, statements

I am getting "End if without block if" while executing below code. I have no idea why.Please help.

```
If erange.Offset(0, 1).Value = "RTN" Then
    If erange.Value = "RASP" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "a"
    If erange.Value = "FEATHER EDGE" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "b"
    If erange.Value = "BIG TAPER" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "c"
    If erange.Value = "SQ & 3SQ" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "d"
    If erange.Value = "SMALL FLAT" Or erange.Value = "BIG FLAT" Or erange.Value = "BIG MILL" Or _
    erange.Value = "SMALL MILL" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "e"
    If erange.Value = "HALF ROUND" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "f"
    If erange.Value = "CHAINSAW" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "g"
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on the last `If`. If you have something directly after `Then` you can't have an `End If`. So, either

```
If erange.Value = "CHAINSAW" Then 
    erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "g"
End If
```

or

```
If erange.Value = "CHAINSAW" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "g"
```

but preferrably

```
If erange.Offset(0, 1).Value = "RTN" Then
    Select Case erange.Value
        Case "RASP"
            erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "a"
        Case "FEATHER EDGE"
            erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "b"
        Case "BIG TAPER"
            erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "c"
        Case "SQ & 3SQ"
            erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "d"
        Case "SMALL FLAT", "BIG FLAT", "BIG MILL", "SMALL MILL"
            erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "e"
        Case "HALF ROUND"
            erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "f"
        Case "CHAINSAW"
            erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "g"
    End Select
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already ending each line with `If` `Then` contitionals. And the first `If` ends on the last line. So the `End If` before that is the culprit.

As @Himanshu Gupta says, use Case. Read about it for example here: http://www.databison.com/vba-select-case-using-vba-select-case-statement-in-excel/

Your fixed code.

```
If erange.Offset(0, 1).Value = "RTN" Then
    If erange.Value = "RASP" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "a"
    If erange.Value = "FEATHER EDGE" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "b"
    If erange.Value = "BIG TAPER" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "c"
    If erange.Value = "SQ & 3SQ" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "d"
    If erange.Value = "SMALL FLAT" Or erange.Value = "BIG FLAT" Or erange.Value = "BIG MILL" Or _
    erange.Value = "SMALL MILL" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "e"
    If erange.Value = "HALF ROUND" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "f"
    If erange.Value = "CHAINSAW" Then erange.Offset(0, 11).Value = "g"
End If
```